# my pdf document is not getting saved on my phone

Tags: android

i am trying to save a PDFDocument on my phone but i am not able too. this is my code;

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath(),"/" +nameGet1 + "-" + idGet1+".pdf");
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of any error that you get?

Comment: i dont get any error, on the emultor everything works fine. but on my real phoen i cant save it

Comment: Then what's the issue with that line of code?

Comment: can you tell us the Android version for your emulator and Real device?

Comment: emultor version 11, phone version 10

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, and make use you have permission to save on phone

```
                download.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(your_file_url));
                    request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(your_file_url));
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, your_file_name);
                    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                });
```

Comment: how to i get the file url?

Comment: Your PDF file is  stored on a web server or what ?